# Loading Content Editor Leads to A Coveo Licensing Error

Tags: coveo, licensing

The site was recently upgrdaded to 8.1 and although I can access the Desktop, the content editor throws an error when launched.

This is a local instance of Sitecore that uses Coveo. After all the database restoration, getting the project working etc. - I go to open the Content Editor only to get a "Could not retrieve Coveo for Sitecore license" message. The Coveo license is in the same folder as the Sitecore license (which is correct since Sitecore login works just fine). I cannot seem to update the Coveo license via the control panel - there is no option to do so.

In fact, I don't even need Coveo to do the work I am trying to get done, I just want to get into the Content Editor - any suggestions?

Comment: If you can give us the versions to and from, it would be very useful.

Comment: can you tell us the solution if you found one please? sirius_b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disabled the `Coveo config` files in the Coveo folder in `App_Config\Includes`, by appending `.example` to the end of each of them. I restarted the website and was able to access the content editor just fine.

I may have been able to download and install the Coveo Sitecore package, but I have not tried that. Will update this if I do.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned upgrading, the way the `coveolicense.xml` is generated is a bit different in the newer `Coveo/Sitecore` versions. The new versions authenticate with the cloud in order to get your org and then write both the `Coveolicense.xml` in the data folder along with `Coveo\ConfigurationEncryptionKeys\IndexingEncryptionKeys` file.

The newer version no longer uses `Datafolder\Coveo\ConfigurationEncryptionKeys\RijndaelEncryptionKeys`

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the coveo for sitecore package?
I have seen this with other developers where the coveo files were referenced on the solution but the sitecore package was not installed on their local builds. Installing it solved the issue

Comment: good point - this is necessary to make sure all the items and files are in place.

Answer (score 0):

Can you navigate to control panel and see if the Coveo section is populated and run the diagnostic. See what component is complaning and may be you will need to relink the coveo admin credentials and validate license.